# AWS ECS DNS resolver for NGINX running with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, service-discovery

I'm using Docker's Compose command with an `ecs` context to launch and orchestrate the containers of a web app for a branch preview feature.

The problem I have is with an Nginx proxy: it can only access the other containers using their CloudMap FQDN (`services.compose-project.local`), and not the short service names.

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/#service-names) is rather clear that both should work:

> Services can retrieve their dependencies using Compose service names (as they do when deploying locally with docker-compose), or optionally use the fully qualified names.

This problem is specific to the Nginx container; the other containers can reach each other using both short names and FQDN just as expected.

Docker's internal DNS server does not seem to be available in ECS:

```
send() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: 127.0.0.11:53
```

The default AWS VPC DNS resolver `169.254.169.253` is responsive, but cannot resolve short names:

```
32#32: *1 webapp could not be resolved (3: Host not found)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42547619/docker-container-cant-resolve-dns-to-reach-another-aws-ec2-machine

Comment: @user973254 unfortunately, that's not an option when you're using Docker with ECS.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Settled with the cloud map FQDN solution.

Comment: @Localist did you have to do anything else (like override the resolver maybe)? or just use the FQDN? I have the same setup and my nginx can't even resolve the FQDN, can you share an example nginx conf file?